# Error: E0018 expected a bracket - need assistance

Tags: c++

```
void RainbowSix::outlineEsp(bool enable) {
{
    unsigned long pid = GetPID("RainbowSix.exe");
    MODULEENTRY32 module = GetModule("RainbowSix.exe", pid);
    HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    unsigned long long addr; //address
    uintptr_t outlineComponent = getOutlineComponent();
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F7));
    WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (byte*)((unsigned long long)outlineComponent + 0x348); //Writting the address to the value of g
}
}
```

I don't see where it is needed, can someone assist me, coding isn't my strongest point but i understand most of it and this is really frustrating me.

Comment: `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F7));` with the `;` here the if () becomes somewhat pointless. Did you mean to call the next line if the condition was true or always? Right now its always called.

Comment: You have a problem with the conditional Clause. Instead of  if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F7));
    WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (byte*)((unsigned long long)outlineComponent + 0x348); //Writting the address to the value of g It should be 
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F7)){
    WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (byte*)((unsigned long long)outlineComponent + 0x348); //Writting the address to the value of g}

Comment: You have two sets of enclosing `{{ .... }}` defining the scope for your function.

Comment: Did the error message give you the line number where the compiler thinks the bracket should go?

Comment: Second time in a couple of answers that I witness the `;` at the end of an `if`. Wonder what the source of that could be. Also, as someone told you, you're lacking a `)` on the `WriteProcessMemory` line. That's the error. It's also odd the double `{{` and `}}`, altough that should be no problem.

Comment: need any clarification on my answer?  I think I covered everything

Answer (score 2):

For the given code there is a brace missing here:

```
WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (byte*)((unsigned long long)outlineComponent + 0x348);
```

You can visualize it by adding new lines and indentation:

```
WriteProcessMemory( // <---- no matching closing brace for that one.
  phandle, (byte*)
  (
    (unsigned long long)outlineComponent + 0x348
  );
```

If you have an IDE or a good editor then those will highlight the corresponding matching brace, if you are over one brace, which helps to find missing braces.

Comment: Don't forget the problem that is `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F7));` - that `;` is *most likely* also a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You have a ";" after you GetAsyncKeyState() call which should be removed.  In addition to this, your [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory) call does not have enough arguments, you are missing the last 3 arguments.

Here is what the correct code should look like:

```C++
void RainbowSix::outlineEsp(bool enable)
{
    unsigned long pid = GetPID("RainbowSix.exe");
    MODULEENTRY32 module = GetModule("RainbowSix.exe", pid);
    HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    unsigned long long addr; //address
    uintptr_t outlineComponent = getOutlineComponent();

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F7) &1)
    {
        WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (byte*)((unsigned long long)outlineComponent + 0x348, lpBuffer, nSize, 0); //Writting the address to the value of g
    }
}
```

lpBuffer is the src buffer which you will write data from, nSize should be how many bytes you want to copy and the 0 as the last argument disregards the optional output variable which would receieve the number of bytes that were successfully written.  You will need to define lpBuffer and nSize to get this code to work.